# IE 11 javascript fetch + lambda

Tags: javascript, lambda, internet-explorer-11, fetch

Today I have learned that all modern browsers - even MS Edge - may live with my work, except IE.
Both 
- lambda funktions using "=>" ; but also 
- fetch() replacing the deprecated xmlhhtp
are not allowed. Is this possible, or do I have some old IE Version (11) stating that the latest KB was installed erroneously?
Thanks

Comment: XHR isn’t deprecated…

Comment: Define "My work". (i'm going to assume you're talking about ES6 for now). in answer to what that would mean for your question ; no, Internet Explorer does not support ES6.

Comment: You could polyfill `fetch` and `Promise` but since arrow functions is new syntax feature you'll need a transpiler (say [babel](https://babeljs.io/))